# Waiting for transaction to be mined - Rinkeby

Tags: rinkeby

Trying to send a contract to Rinkeby. I get *waiting for transaction to be mined* indefinitely.

Any ideas why it's not mining? Seems to be fine on rinkeby.io.

Injection Web3 from Remix IDE via Metamask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible reasons is that gas price is too low, so miners don't want to take your transaction for mining.

Another possible reason is that network is/was overloaded. You can check number of pending transactions in the network [here](https://etherscan.io/txsPending)